# meaning of error message

Tags: c++

what does this error message mean?
destination of memory copy is too small

Comment: It means the destination of a memory copy is too small...

Answer (score 3):

It means that the compiler has detected that you are copying memory to a location which is too small to hold it.

The is not something the compiler can necessarily tell in advance. However when it can detect it, this is the warning you get.

For a more detailed explanation see this:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/09/01/compiler-warning-c4789.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Means you have breached the memory you allocated for your resource.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some method is trying to copy data whose size is too large for the destination data block. Look for strcpy, memcpy or similar commands.

It would be easier to help if you posted some code though.